# Connection slow from node to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm experimenting with docker and reflected a very slow connection from the nodejs (4.2.3) container to mongodb (3.2) container.

My setup, very basic, is this (docker-compose):

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - "./app:/src/app"
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    links:
      - "db_cache:redis"
      - "db:mongodb"
    command: nodemon -L app/bin/www

  db_cache:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: mongo
```

My s.o. is OSX 10.10 and the docker version is 1.10.2.

The strange thing is that the connection time to the db is always 30 seconds.

Is there any automatic delay?

**EDIT:**

if I set ip address of mongodb container intead a "dns" (`mongodb`), the delay disappears!

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the connection string from the node app? Is it via an IP address or by a name being looked up in DNS? For the latter, slow connection resolves are typically a reverse lookup zone problem where no such entry is defined. Not really a programming problem in that case.

Comment: The url string is `mongodb://mongodb:27017/dockertest` reading the documentation docker this is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This does not completely solve the problem, but it allows you to restore the normal behavior.**

The cause of this seems to be the version 2 of the `docker-compose.yml`.

If I remove the version 2 is completely eliminated the 30-second delay when connecting to mongodb:

```
web:
  build: ./app
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "80:3000"
  links:
    - "db_cache:redis"
    - "db:mongodb"
  command: nodemon -L app/bin/www

db_cache:
  image: redis
db:
  image: mongo
```

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3072).